# How do I install the hstore module on PostgreSQL 9.0 (MacPorts install)?

Tags: postgresql, module, installation, macports

I have a lovely PostgreSQL 9.0 server installed on my laptop via MacPorts. I would like to enable the [hstore module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html), but I can't find any instructions for installing these optional modules (nor can I find any hstore-related code in `/opt/local/share/postgresql90/contrib/`).

I *have* found some hstore-related SQL [here](https://github.com/marcelor/django-postgresql-hstore/blob/master/management/commands/enable_hstore.py), but I'm not sure where it comes from or if it's compatible w/ PostgreSQL 9.0.

So, how do I enable the hstore module on my MacPorts-installed Postgres 9.0 server?

Comment: Checkout @rpkelly's answer below, it's the most simple and most complete.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can tell MacPorts to build hstore. Here's how.

If you already have `postgresql` installed, you will need to uninstall it first (this won't touch your data or users) because the `install` action will not re-install an already installed port.  The uninstall is forced (`-f`) because `postgresql91-server` is dependent and will prevent uninstall.

```
sudo port -f uninstall postgresql91
```

Edit the Portfile and add `hstore` to the list on the line which begins with `set contribs`:

```
sudo port edit postgresql91
```

(Re)install from source explicitly (`-s`) to build the hstore extension:

```
sudo port -s install postgresql91
```

Then load hstore, once for each of your databases in which you want to use it:

In >= 9.1: `CREATE EXTENSION hstore;`

In 9.0: `psql -U postgres -f /opt/local/share/postgresql90/contrib/hstore.sql`

Note this process works for postgresql92 by just substituting "92" for "91".

Comment: These are the best / most simple instructions. @rpkelly: I edited them to include uninstalling first, which was necessary in my setup (and doesn't add any steps or overhead so it seems like a safe bet).

Comment: Note **once for each of your databases**!

Comment: Works for any extension that is not already included such as xml2

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the port for PostgreSQL 9.1 now includes hstore, but it still needs to be enabled. Install and start the database normally.

```
sudo port install postgresql91 postgresql91-server
sudo mkdir -p /opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/defaultdb
sudo chown postgres:postgres /opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/defaultdb
sudo su postgres -c '/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/initdb \
  -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql91/defaultdb'
sudo port load postgresql91-server
```

EDIT: Installing in another computer didn't work as well. The hstore was not installed with the base (I may have made it available trying other solutions). So do this BEFORE the load command above:

```
sudo port unload postgresql91-server #  if you did load above
sudo port build postgresql91
port work postgresql91 # Gives you base dir for following command
cd /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_postgresql91/postgresql91/work/postgresql-9.1.*/contrib/hstore
sudo make all
sudo make install clean
sudo port load postgresql91-server
```

To enable the hstore extension, use the new "create extension" SQL command in the database(s) you will use hstore. If you install it into the template1 database, all databases created afterwards will have the hstore extension.

```
psql template1 postgres
template1=# create extension hstore;
```

If you only need the extension in a particular database:

```
psql dbname dbuser
dbname=# create extension hstore;
create table a (id serial, data hstore);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "a_id_seq" for serial column "a.id"
CREATE TABLE
dbname=# insert into a(data) values('a=>1, b=>2');
INSERT 0 1
dbname=# SELECT * from a;
 id |        data        
----+--------------------
  1 | "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for MacOS (or whatever MacPorts is), but on Windows there is a file "hstore.sql" in share/contrib and it references a library "hstore.dll" which is part of the regular distribution.

This was included in the one click installer from EnterpriseDB. I would assume that the one click installer for MacOS includes that module as well:

http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx

Comment: I might try using the EnterpriseDB installer. I can't seem to find it in the MacPorts distribution.

Comment: I don't know whether MacOS is binary compatible with that MacPort thing, but there is a "zip" version of the EnterpriseDB package. It does contain a hstore.so file and the necessary .sql script. You can get that from here: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload

Comment: Sorry, MacPorts is a common 3rd-party package manager for the Unixy side of MacOS (close cousin to the BSD ports project, I believe). Probably binary compatible. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Joey Adam's solution is correct, but has become slightly dated with postgres 9.1:

I did the following differently from his post:

- Instead of using postgresql-server-devel, I ran 'sudo port install postgresql91-server' (the former has been replaced by the latter)
- The Makefile in contrib/hstore has been updated to use PGXS (it looks basically just like Joey posted above); I did not have to edit it.
- I did go ahead and make a sym link to /somewhere/in/my/path/pg_config > /opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config, so that the Makefile would succeed (it expects pg_config in your path)
- 9.1 has a different way of handling extension such as hstore; for example, to enable hstore, I did psql91 [my_schema], then > create extension hstore (you can read more here about extensions http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/sql-createextension.html)

Comment: Thanks. I don't have 9.1 to test on, but this is important information.

Comment: Update: on a mac, I just install from source.  It works, it's easy, and I have full control and don't have to figure out how to push port around to give me what I need.