# How do I install the hstore module on PostgreSQL 9.1?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I have seen there is already a question on the subject concerning 9.0 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776563/how-do-i-install-the-hstore-module-on-postgresql-9-0-macports-install) but it is more than one year old. Has anything changed since then?

I have 9.1 already installed on Snow Leopard. Which steps should I follow to install hstore?

(I am not familiar with MacPorts by the way).

Comment: Doesn't `create extension hstore` work? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html

Comment: Right, I did create the extension hstore. ("Query returned successfully with no result in 695 ms."). Now what should I do? Is the new extension an empty box? Should I run a a SQL script in it?

Comment: It provides you with a datatype `hstore` that you can use. What do you expect to get? Did you read the manual?

Comment: That should be it.  a_hour_with_no_name is right. It provides you with the hstore type and also a approximately 70 functions (e.g. exist(hstore, text)).  You should be able to see them under public>functions in pgAdminIII.